# How to use IloExprArray in code?

Tags: c++, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, cplex, ilog

I have just started to use `cplex` library and get stuck in defining `IloExprArray` in my code. Here is my snippet of code:

```
IloExprArray diff;
diff= IloExprArray(iloEnv,list.size());
for( int i=1; i<=10; i++ ) {
    for( int j=0; j<9; j++ ) {
         double weight = globalObjects->value.at(j)->getmyproperty(i);

         diff[j] += ( Ycfg[i][j]*Ycfg[i][j] - 2*weight*Ycfg[i][j] + weight*weight );
//where Ycfg is IloArray<IloNumVarArray>

    }
}
```

But whenever i am running this code it get stuck at `diff[j] += ..` line. I also searched on net but didn't get good documentation except of official one. Another question What about if i use `IloArray <IloExpr>` instead of `IloExprArray` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initialization code

```
diff = IloExprArray(iloEnv, list.size())
```

creates an array of empty [handles](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cosinfoc/v12r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Filog.odms.cplex.help%2Frefcppcplex%2Fhtml%2Fhandle-class.html). Handles are essentially ILOG's [smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm).  When you do a += on an empty handle, you are essentially doing it on a null pointer.  You need to initialize all the handles.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
     diff[i] = IloExpr(iloEnv);
```

There are other suspicious parts of your code that could be causing you trouble.  For example, the outer for-loop runs from 1 to 10, and you use list.size() as the length of diff, but your is `for (j = 0; j< 9; ++j)` instead of `for (j = 0; j < list.size(); ++j)`